# Trying to access a variable globally

Tags: c#, timer, double

I have a maze game and I'm trying to create two Timers at a time. 
1st (Exits the game after 300 secs)

```
t1.Interval = 30000;
t1.Enabled = true;
t1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(hiddenTimer);

public static void hiddenTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

2nd (Displays the time remaining every 1 sec (like a real timer))

```
t2.Interval = 1000;
t2.Enabled = true;
t2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(showTimer);

public static void showTimer(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write(timeLeft);
    }
```

I would want to pass declare timeLeft globally but it says that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property..."

How would I declare it properly?

Comment: 1 sec == 1000 msecs, so t1.Interval=300000, add one 0

Comment: Please post all of your code.  You did not post the declaration of timeLeft.  The problem is obvious your trying to use a non-static property within a static method.

Comment: Both of my timers are working but i have a problem displaying the 2ndTimer because it's a maze game, My cursor keeps moving that's why the Time follows my cursor. any suggestion how would i fix this?

Comment: How are you writing the time?  Are you actually using Console.WriteLine?

Comment: Then when you go to write the time, save the current position, move the position to where you want to display the time, write the time, then restore the position.

Comment: it's too fast. now my avatar 'Ö' is leaving trails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should declare your timeLeft as a static if you want it to behave like a global variable.

Secondly I'd use one timer and keep track of the time separately for each event:

```
static DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
static DateTime lastTime = DateTime.Now;
```

In your timer, which should be set to something to give more accuracy like 1/10 of a second, do this:

```
if (DateTime.Now - lastTime > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1))
   // Update the time here for your 1s clock
lastTime = DateTime.Now;

if (DateTime.Now - startTime > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 300))
    // Exit the game
```

Your timings will be more accurate this way.

Comment: how would i suppose to do that? any suggestions?

Comment: @Filip, that's funny you would be so competitive to post that comment on my answer.

Comment: that would be helpful but i have a new problem. can you help me display the Time in one place only? the time follows the track of my cursor which i am using to move the avatar inside the maze.

Comment: @ Filip @ Ares your revisions are both working. thanks you very much. i would be more grateful i you could help me with my another problem. :D

Comment: @AresAvatar, Comment removed, I did not mean to offend by saying that I also made an example of it. I was already in Visual Studio doing it when I saw that he wrote "how would I do that".

Comment: @Filip, you didn't offend me, I thought it was funny.  I love the competitiveness on StackOverflow.

Comment: @AresAvatar, "competition" is what drives good answers. :) I honestly didn't mean it like that though, I just want to help out.

Comment: @Filip: I agree, that's why I love it.  You obviously help out a lot -- you have a very high reputation!

Answer (score 7):

By making a static property:

```
public static Double TimeLeft { get; set; }
```

This is if you want to Publicliy accessable from your entire context, if you want it private, just change `public` to `private`.

Just a side note, the built in `Timer` doesn't support polling for the remaining time until the next elapse. Either you decrease `TimeLeft` in each `Elapse`-event on the 1sec timer or you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278525/system-timers-timer-how-to-get-the-time-remaining-until-elapse/2278550#2278550).

**Edit**

Here is one way to do it with one timer, first I declare two properties and one constant field that I use, don't bother that they are static, it's just easier to run it as a console application this way.

```
public static Timer SystemTimer { get; set; }
public static double Elapsed { get; set; }

private const double CycleInterval = 1000;
```

Then in my `Main`-method  I have the following to initiate my `Timer`

```
SystemTimer = new Timer();
SystemTimer.Interval = CycleInterval;
SystemTimer.Enabled = true;
SystemTimer.Elapsed += Cycle;

SystemTimer.Start();
```

Having this, the `Cycle`-event handler can look like this:

```
static void Cycle(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Elapsed += CycleInterval;

    if ((Elapsed%5000) == 0.0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("5 sec elapsed!");
        // Do stuff each 5 sec
    }

    if ((Elapsed % 10000) == 0.0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("10 sec elapsed!");
        // Do stuff each 10 sec
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", Elapsed);
}
```

You could also have `Elapsed` being a `TimeSpan`, but you can refactor this as you like.

Here's my complete source code that I used:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Timer SystemTimer { get; set; }
        public static double Elapsed { get; set; }

        private const double CycleInterval = 1000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SystemTimer = new Timer();
            SystemTimer.Interval = CycleInterval;
            SystemTimer.Enabled = true;
            SystemTimer.Elapsed += Cycle;

            SystemTimer.Start();

            while (true) ;

        }

        static void Cycle(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Elapsed += CycleInterval;

            if ((Elapsed%5000) == 0.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("5 sec elapsed!");
                // Do stuff each 5 sec
            }

            if ((Elapsed % 10000) == 0.0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("10 sec elapsed!");
                // Do stuff each 10 sec
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}", Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like when I run it:

[image]

Comment: yeah. i already added a timeLeft--; in the showTimer() method. my problem now is how to write the time. my cursor keeps moving sice it's a maze game that's why my cursor leaves a trail of time! lol. i know this is an another problem, but please help me if you can. :D

Comment: @Reinan, Updated my answer again with an example on how to do it with one timer, might be easier to read your code in the end instead of having a lot of timers. But keep in mind, this is just one way, using a `TimeSpan` is also a nice way to do it.

Comment: @Reinan, I don't quite follow you on the other problem. If your initial problem is now solved, mark the answer that helped you solve your problem as Accepted. Then create a new question with the other problem.

Comment: @Filip I'm sorry i'm new here i'm not really used to how things work here :D

Comment: i would post another question, please take a look at my post later one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711853/c-fixing-timer-in-a-place
please help me with this one

Comment: @Reinan, I gathered that you are new, and Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Mark it static:

```
public static int TimeLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `timeLeft` memeber is not **static**.

Make it **static** or make `showTimer` method **non** static.

Regards.