# Text/Cursor Positioning in Console

Tags: c#, console

[image: Time Display Problem]

Any of you guys suggest how could i display the time just on top of the [x] Exit ?
I'm currently using Console.Write() and ch.gotoxy() which sets my cursor into different places

(btw, my cursor is 'Ö' beside 293)

Comment: where is the problem? doesn't `gotoxy(needed position); writeline(time);` work?

Comment: yes. but unfortunately, im also using gotoxy to move my avatar(Ö) inside the maze.

Comment: well, you can `gotoxy(back)` afterwards, cannot you?

Comment: If this code is open source by any chance, can you post a link to it? I'm curious, I've never done any advanced console oriented programming in Windows/.NET before. If it's not open source, no big deal.

Comment: honestly, i still don't know what open source is. but if you're asking if i downloaded the code from the net, then no. i made it myself. :D

Comment: @Reinan, He mean if you can share your code, more of us are curios on how you've done this! :)

Comment: Pastebin maybe http://pastebin.com/

Comment: i could send this to you guys if you want.

Comment: ok i'll register in pastebin.com

Comment: @Conrad about pastebin, can you access the file even though i put it in private mode?

Comment: ASCII mazes! [That takes me back.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZZT) :)

Comment: @Matt Greer check http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Working-with-Console-Screen-Buffers-in-NET/ for an article on windows console-mode programming

Comment: for those interested in maze generation, check the source for pretty much any rouge-like (Dungeons Of Moria, Nethack,Angband, etc.)  I have a codeplex project for a silverlight port of Moria.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried but, what about creating a different Thread (or Task in the new TPL) that only writes the time? You'll need to share your cursor position between the two Threads and use some locking system while using Console.SetCursorPosition.

Answer (score 1):

There is an int under Console called CursorLeft and CursorTop. CursorLeft is your X coordinates and CursorTop is your Y. Just use that to set your position