# Executing methods at a specified time

Tags: .net-core, time

I would like to execute method at a specified time e.g. execute some method in five minutes. I don't need to execute it in interval ( every day or every hour), just once. 
I making web application with asp.net core 2.1. I would like to be able to add e.g. 3 jobs to do
1) in 5 min
2) in 10 min
3) in 15 min
and expecting to perform when time is over.
How can I do it in a simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use timers. Simple and easy...

```
private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
private int minutes = Settings.Default.5MinuteTimer;

private void SetTimer()
{
    myTimer= new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 60 * minutes);          
    myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    myTimer.AutoReset = false; //Fire event only once.
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod();
}

private MyMethod()
{
    myTimer.Stop(); //Calling stop will also Dispose the timer.
    // Other code.
}
```

Comment: ok, but if i would like to know how much time is left? is there easy way to check this. e.g. I planned to do some work in 5 hours. After 3 hours I want to know how much longer do I have to wait.
I think that I have to do it for my own but maybe you can help me

Comment: @Indigo_heart Check out this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2278550/229930